# How do I pass String input from a webpage to @RestController as a Java object?

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My question is very basic.

I have the following html:

```html
<form action="/login" method="GET">
  <div>
    Id: <input type="text" name="id" value="id"/>
    Name:  <input type="text" name="name" value="name"/>
  </div>
    <button>Login</button>
 </form>
```

And the following `@GetMapping` method to which I want to connect:

```php
 @GetMapping("/login")
  public String someLogin(LoginObject obj, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //do something
  }
```

`LoginObject` is composed from two fields: `id` and `name`, which I am taking from the UI. How do I convert two strings to my `LoginObject` and then pass it to the `@RestController`

Comment: @Taplar I edited my question as per your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to decide form method (POST/GET). Than annotate your rest controller. Here is the small example for you;

```
<form action="/demo/add" method="get">
    <label>Username</label><input type="text" id="username" name="username"> 
    <label>Email</label><input type="email" id="email" name="email">
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

And Rest Controller;

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/demo")
public class WebController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@GetMapping(path="/add")
public @ResponseBody String addUser(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String email) {
    User u = new User();
    u.setUsername(username);
    u.setEmail(email);
    userRepository.save(u);
    return "SUCCESS!";
}
```

}